# Fixed length menu

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I would like to have two level menu like below:

Item1 | **Item2** | Item3

**Item2.1** | Item 2.2 | Item 2.3

How can I write sitemap file and MenuHelperModel to obtain effect like above?

EDIT: I created sitemap file like this:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="MyApp" clickable="false">
   <mvcSiteMapNode title="Item1" controller="Item11">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Item1.1" controller="Item11" />
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Item1.2" controller="Item12" />
   </mvcSiteMapNode>
   ...
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

Unfortunately IsInCurrentPath is true only for MyApp node, so I can't highlight correct item.

Comment: Have you tried to define the corresponding controller actions on the nodes?

Comment: There is no corresponding controller to the MyApp node.

Answer (score 0):

As Xharze pointed out, you must specify the controller action in order for MvcSiteMapProvider nodes to function with MVC.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="MyApp" clickable="false">
   <mvcSiteMapNode title="Item1" controller="Item11" action="Index">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Item1.1" controller="Item11" action="Decimal1" />
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Item1.2" controller="Item12" action="Decimal2" />
   </mvcSiteMapNode>
   ...
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

The fact that the MyApp node is not clickable just means it will be a non-clickable grouping node and it is not necessary to provide a controller or action in this case.

For the other nodes, the controller and action parameters must correspond to MVC controllers and actions.

```
public class Item1Controller : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Decimal1()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Decimal2()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

For example, the `<mvcSiteMapNode title="Item1.1" controller="Item11" action="Decimal1" />` node would correspond with the Decimal1 action method above because both the controller name and action name match.